# Excel Worksheet_Change not triggering with cell value update

Tags: excel, vba, plc, opc, dde

I´ve done some extensive research, but cannot solve my problem. I have an Excel workbook where I constantly pull a value from an OPC server. The value is stored in a set of rows. This works perfectly whenever I introduce the data manually, but when the cell is automatically updated, it does not work.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    'MsgBox = Target.Address
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("B1:B2"), Range(target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Call CopyDataToRecord
    End If
End Sub

Sub CopyDataToRecord()

    Dim IndexI As Integer
    Dim IndexY As Integer
    Dim IndexMius As Integer
    Dim DufferLength As Integer
    
    DufferLength = 20
    IndexY = DufferLength + 5
    
    'Shift Data
    For IndexI = i To DufferLength
        IndexYMius = IndexY - 1
        Cells(IndexY, 1) = Cells(IndexYMius, 1)
        Cells(IndexY, 2) = Cells(IndexYMius, 2)
        IndexY = IndexYMius
    Next IndexI
    
    'Copy The Latest Data
    Range("A2:B2").Copy Range("A5:B5")
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Did you put the code in the worksheet object? Or did you put it into a module by mistake?

Comment: There are only 3 reasons why an event procedure doesn't fire. (1) The procedure is formatted wrongly. The one you posted looks perfect but better let VBA create it for you. (2) `Application.EnableEvents = False`. Restarting Excel will set the property to True. (3) The event occurs but isn't recognized. This would be because the procedure isn't in the worksheet's code module as @braX has suggested. Move it to that code module.

Comment: The Change event does not fire when a cell is updated _by a formula_.  If that's the case for you, you'll need to change to the Calculate event, or schedule an update with OnTime in VBA.  Both are well covered on SO

Answer (score 0):

Your code (a bit adapted to declare `i` and `IndexYMius`) works well on my Excel sheet.
I would just recommend to prevent recursive `Worksheet_Change` calls by protecting the changes with `Application.EnableEvents`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    'MsgBox = Target.Address
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("B1:B2"), Range(target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call CopyDataToRecord
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

BTW, if your code is not triggered by the automatic update process, it might be because this process includes somewhere an `Application.EnableEvents = False` that prevents the `Worksheet_Change` to be executed.